# How to get Total Time in a location

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to this forums, I have a question on How to get the time stayed in a location. Suppose if i have the following data

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ID          INT,
    LOCATION VARCHAR(10),
    DT DATETIME
)

insert into @T VALUES
(1,'ED','01/01/2019 12:01' ),
(2,'ED','01/01/2019 02:01' ),
(3,'ED','01/01/2019 05:01' ),
(4,'AB','01/02/2019 02:01' ),
(5,'AB','01/03/2019 02:01' ),
(6,'ED','01/03/2019 19:01' ),
(7,'ED','01/04/2019 02:01' )


select * from @t
```

How can i get the total time stayed in a location?

The end result should look like

in

```
  ED from 01/01/2019 12:01 to 01/02/2019 02:01 
  AB from 01/02/2019 02:01 to 01/03/2019 19:01
  ED from 01/03/2019 19:01 to 01/04/2019 02:01
```

thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Why `ED from 01/01/2019 12:01 to 01/02/2019 02:01` and not `ED from 01/01/2019 12:01 to 01/02/2019 05:01`?

Comment: If an employee moved to other location, then the entry time of the new location will be the end time of last location. In this came the employee moved to Location AB on 01/02/2019 @ 02:01, so he is in ED from 01/01/2019 12:01 to 01/02/2019 02:01.

Comment: please see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 you can run this to find difference in minute   SELECT DateDiff(MINUTE,'01/03/2019 19:01 ', '01/04/2019 02:01') AS DateDiff;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this does what you want:

```
select location, min(dt), max(coalesce(next_dt, dt))
from (select t.*, lead(dt) over (order by dt) as next_dt,
             row_number() over (partition by location order by dt) as seqnum_l,
             row_number() over (order by dt) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by location, (seqnum - seqnum_l)
order by min(dt);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3b83aacbb27eddf88ccdcf02e255b139) is a db<>fiddle.

This is a variation of the gaps-and-islands problem.  The challenge is getting the ending date time, which is on the next record.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be done using a similar query:

```
CREATE TABLE #TBL
(
    ID          INT,
    LOCATION VARCHAR(10),
    DT DATETIME
)

insert into #TBL VALUES
(1,'ED','01/01/2019 12:01' ),
(2,'ED','01/01/2019 02:01' ),
(3,'ED','01/01/2019 05:01' ),
(4,'AB','01/02/2019 02:01' ),
(5,'AB','01/03/2019 02:01' ),
(6,'ED','01/03/2019 19:01' ),
(7,'ED','01/04/2019 02:01' )

WITH CTE_1 AS (SELECT LOCATION, DT,  
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY ID) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LOCATION ORDER BY ID)  as [group]
               FROM #TBL)
SELECT LOCATION,   MIN(DT) FromDate, MAX(DT) ToDate
FROM CTE_1
GROUP BY LOCATION, [group]
ORDER BY FromDate
```

*Result*

[image]

Comment: If you group by, for the above query the result will be only 2 rows right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time Hadi, Your query worked too.

Comment: @Streetfighter you should accept Gordon answer since he was faster in posting the correct query. Good luck